# Specify pipe output position

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I want to do stuff like this:

```
echo myserver:~/dir/2/ | rsync -r HERE /local/path/
```

I want the output redirected to a specified location in the command. The echo stuff goes "HERE". What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Is there any purpose with your command that this `rsync -r myserver:~/dir/2/ /local/path/` doesn't prove it?

Comment: Yes, proof of concept. My real script is long and hard to read, so I made this one.

Comment: Didn't get you mean! You mean `myserver:~/dir/2/` resulting from a script as its output and it's `/to/ooo/ooo/oooo/looooong/path` that you don't want to type in `rsync`?! Then [PSkocik's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399505/72456) is better choice` (surly I cannot change your choice)

Comment: Yeah and I have variables that I can't even keep track of anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `xargs` or exactly this requirement. You can use the `-I` as place-holder for the input received from the pipeline, do

```
echo "myserver:${HOME}/dir/2/" | xargs -I {} rsync -r "{}" /local/path/
```

(or) use `~` without double-quotes under which it does not expand to the `HOME` directory path.

```
echo myserver:~/dir/2/ | xargs -I {} rsync -r "{}" /local/path/
```

Comment: `xargs` seems overkill for something where simple command substitution (`$()`) will do...

Comment: @marcelm : Thanks for the feedback. Yes I just wanted to show one of the many options possible to do. It is up to the OP to choose the best option. Am sure it didn’t deserve a -ve vote

Answer (score 9):

This

```
 rsync -r "$(echo myserver:~/dir/2/)" /local/path/
```

is the easiest way to do it.

Piping connects stdouts with stdins. Here you want the output to go to an argument, so you need something else than classical piping.

That something is *command substitution* (`$()`).

Answer (score 2):

You may give `rsync` a list of files to download in a file or on standard input by using `--files-from`:

```
echo "dir/2/" | rsync --files-from=- -r user@server: /local/path/
```

The `-` makes `rsync` read from standard input.  The server can't be given to `rsync` in this manner. There will only be a single connection made to the server and all files will be transferred over that connection.

If you use `-a` or `--archive` with `--files-from` then you need to explicitly add `-r` or `--recursive` if you want to recursion since that option, even though it's part of `-a`, is disabled when `--files-from` is used.